# Sql query to Linq using subquery

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

Actually,I'm getting a `list of top 5 countires based on count` like this :

```
select top 5 COUNT(distinct FROM_EMAILID) as Count, 
FROM_COUNTRY from SURVEY_VISITORS  
where TEMPLATE_ID=79 and FROM_COUNTRY<>'undefined' 
group by FROM_COUNTRY order by COUNT desc
```

Now,I need to convert into Linq,but unable to do it.

I have tried using subqueries like this for getting top 1 country.but for top 5 countries,I was bit confused :

```
 var innerQuery = (from t in VDC.SURVEY_VISITORS
                   group t by new
                   {
                      t.FROM_COUNTRY
                   } into g
                   orderby
                   g.Count() descending
                   select new
                   {
                     VisitorCount = (Int64?)g.Count(),
                     Country = g.Key.FROM_COUNTRY
                   }).FirstOrDefault();

   var result = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_VISITORS
                  where ((innerQuery.Country.Contains(xx.FROM_COUNTRY)) 
                   && xx.TEMPLATE_ID == 79)
                   select new
                    {
                       xx.FROM_COUNTRY,
                       xx.FROM_EMAILID
                     }).Distinct().ToList();
```

My result should be :
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works Perfect for me.

```
var query = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_VISITORS
             where xx.TEMPLATE_ID == tempid
             group xx by new { xx.FROM_COUNTRY } into g
             select new
             {
                Count = g.Select(act => act.FROM_EMAILID).Distinct().Count(),
                g.Key.FROM_COUNTRY
             }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).Take(5);
```

Comment: Actions order is not right, you first take 5, then ordering them, should order first, then take 5. Also materialization happens at select, so it is not exact replica of your sql, it receives all records for database and then does ordering and top 5, so you're receiving more records from database as you would with sql.

Comment: }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).Take(5); works perfect ryt?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, if `OrderBy` would swallow that complex expression, but try this:

```
SurveyVisitors
    .Where(x => x.TemplateId = 79 && x.FromCountry != "undefined")
    .GroupBy(x => x.FromCountry)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Select(y => y.FromEmailId).Distinct().Count())
    .Take(5)
    .Select(new => {
        Count = x.Select(y => y.FromEmailId).Distinct().Count(),
        FromCountry = x.Key
    })
```